# npm publish always fails with E503 or ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT even with excellent network quality & cannot even publish a 200B package

Tags: npm, publish, connection-timeout

To publish my 200B npm package (just for demo) I have already logged in to npm using `npm login`. But running `npm publish --access publish`, makes me wait for 5 mins and then fails with ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT.
I am publishing it from termux on Android via jio network mobile phone hotspot. Also I have excellent network quality but still it never succeds to connect.

I tried downgrading to npm 8. Now I am getting E503 instead of ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT contrary to status.npmjs.org 100% uptime & operational status for `npm publsh`.
Nothing i found on internet works for me to publish my package

[image: my network specs]

Answer (score 0):

In my company i am the main mantainer for every npm package we have.
There are days where i have to publish tens of new versions, and only in the last 5-10 days I noticed an embarassing degradation of service during the hours around 14 UTC - 16 UTC

Publishing packages takes tens of seconds, sometimes minutes, and frequently i too have some 503

They are probably doing something behind the scene that they feel like should not impact users (hence no update in the status page) but it is definitely noticeable, at least for me